# Android aes encryption pad block corrupted

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I am using the methods below and if I enter the right key everything works fine. 
But if I enter a wrong key I am receiving a BadPaddingException:pad block corrupted...
Am I doing something wrong?

```
public  void initKey(String passwd, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException{

    byte[] localsalt = salt; 
   PBEKeySpec password = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray(),localsalt, 1024,128);//, localsalt, 1000, 128);  //128bit enc aes
   SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5And128BitAES-CBC-OpenSSL","BC");  
   PBEKey key = (PBEKey) factory.generateSecret(password);  
   encKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
}


public   String txt2enc(String etxt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

       final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");//AES       
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encKey);      

       byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal((etxt).getBytes("UTF-8"));
       return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, 0);
}

//decryption
public  String txt2dec(String dtxt) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, encKey);
    byte[] decrypt = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(dtxt, 0));
    return new String(decrypt);//return Base64.encodeToString(decrypt, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. It's expected. This is technically a duplicate of [Java Encryption issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463687/java-encryption-issue) (which doesn't seem to be easy to find). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463687/java-encryption-issue/2464360#2464360) for a good explanation. You can consider adding a MAC (Message Authentication Code) to safely accomplish something more like a checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Other than supplying the wrong key, I don't think so :)

A stack trace would help, so we can see which function is throwing the BadPaddingException.

This may well be because the 'bad' key is a different length to the 'good' key - does the 'bad' key come out of initKey() or somewhere else?

Best wishes,

Phil Lello

Comment: the BadPaddingException comes when i try to decrypt the passwd which is stored in a Base64 format..The passwd is the passwd that the user(now I insert it) insert.So you think that it's ok the exception when i enter a wrong key?(When I say wrong I mean that I am trying to decrypt a string with a different than the encryption key)

Comment: If it's coming out of the Base64.decode, then dtxt isn't a valid Base64-encoded string. As an invalid string isn't a valid password, I'd just catch the Exception and treat as failure. If dtxt is generated internally in the app, I'd look into why it has an invalid encoding.